# Counting occurrence by giving start and end points

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Let's say A1:AF1 contains only a, b, or c (one of the three letters). By giving a start and end, how do I count the occurrence of a, b, and c in the given range? For example, if I give 1 and 5, I want to count the occurrence of a, b, and c in A1 to E1. If I give 10 and 25, I want to count the occurrence in J1 to Y1. A formula-based solution is preferred.

Comment: You are right. My mistake. It should be A1 to E1 or J1:Y1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 10 in A3 and 25 in A4 you can count *a, b* and *c* in J1:Y1 with,

```
'count a, b and c
=sum(countif(index(1:1, , a3):index(1:1, , c1), {"a", "b", "c"}))
'count a
=countif(index(1:1, , a3):index(1:1, , a4), "a")
'count b
=countif(index(1:1, , a3):index(1:1, , a4), "b")
'count c
=countif(index(1:1, , a3):index(1:1, , a4), "c")
```